# Avoiding destructor call for a specific exception

Tags: c++

I'm simplifying my problem here since I have a pretty large codebase and I can't make a mcve.

I have an object which might or might not be constructed successfully. If not, an exception of kind `ObjectUnsupported` is thrown in its constructor

```
class Object {
public:
  Object() {

    read_data1();
    ..
    if(unsupported_kind == true)
      throw ObjectUnsupported();
    ..
    read_data2();
  }
  std::vector<char> data1;
  std::vector<char> data2;
};
```

`data1` is **always** read while `data2` is only available for supported objects.

Now, I'm trying to construct an object somewhere else by using a smart pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> obj;
try {
  obj = std::make_unique<Object>();
} catch(ObjectUnsupported& ex) {
  object_is_unsupported = true;
}

if(object_is_unsupported) {
  if(checkIfDataIsNeeded(obj->data1) == false)
    return; // We didn't need it anyway
  else
    throw RuntimeError(); // Data was needed! Abort!
}
```

`data1` is always read while `data2` is not but the point here is: I might need that `data2` or I might **not** need the object at all.

The code above doesn't work since the destructor for the `obj` smart pointer is called therefore rendering my subsequent code wrong.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: while not a very clean solution, you could try extending your exception to hold a std::vector<char> and copy data2 into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an exception from a constructor does not leave you with a half-constructed object. By design, that object does not exist. All the members that were constructed up till the point of the exception will be destroyed.

The solution here is for your object to support a flag that indicates how much data it has.

for example:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object() {

        read_data1();
        ..
        if(!unsupported_kind)
        {
            read_data2();
            _has_supported_data = true;
        }
    }

    bool has_supported_data() const {
        return _has_supported_data;
    }

    std::vector<char> data1;
    std::vector<char> data2;

private:
    bool _has_supported_data = false;
};
```